# Detect if contole Activix is enabled in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

I'm developing a Webpage that contains an automatic download .

```
<iframe height="0" width ="0" src="http://aa.bb/cc.pdf"></iframe>
```

This page cannot be displayed in browser that enable Activex filtering. I want to develop script that detects if Activex is disabled that it will starts download automatically . I find some answers but scripts doesn't work in recent Browser .

Comment: Can someone help me ?

Comment: You would need ... ehh ... an ActiveX to detect the ActiveX filter.

Comment: Script that detects if an Activex is enabled or not ?  @Teemu

Comment: No, an ActiveX object only can detect if the ActiveX filter is on or off.

Comment: What means an Activex filter is on or off? It means that it is enabled or not ? Or installed or not ?

Comment: Enabled or not, it is always installed, no need to detect that.

Comment: I find some script and tested it to find if Activex is enabled or not .And it always give me wrong result :/